# Seven Segment Multiplexing on Basys2

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl, synthesis, multiplexing

this is my first post so I hope I'm doing this correctly. I'm trying to output a "4 3 2 1" on a four digit seven segment display on a BASYS2 board. I have checked to make sure that 0 enables the signal and that I have the ports mapped correctly. I believe the error is within my multiplexing logic since I am only able to display a single digit. I'm new to Verilog (am used to C) and would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module main (clock, AN0, AN1, AN2, AN3, CA, CB, CC, CD, CE, CF, CG, CDP);


//USED FOR SEVEN SEG
input clock;

output AN0, AN1, AN2, AN3, CA, CB, CC, CD, CE, CF, CG, CDP;

reg [7:0] cathodedata; //cathode data
reg [3:0] anodedata; //anode data
reg [2:0] digit = 1;
reg [6:0] data;
reg setdp;
reg [19:0] counter = 0;

assign CA = cathodedata [7];
assign CB = cathodedata [6];
assign CC = cathodedata [5];
assign CD = cathodedata [4];
assign CE = cathodedata [3];
assign CF = cathodedata [2];
assign CG = cathodedata [1];
assign CDP = cathodedata [0];
assign AN3 = anodedata [3];
assign AN2 = anodedata [2];
assign AN1 = anodedata [1];
assign AN0 = anodedata [0];
//USED FOR SEVEN SEG

    //Multiplexing
    //Board Clock: 50MHz
    //p = t*f
    //t = 16ms
    //p = 16ms * 50*10^6 = 800,000 cycles
    //200,000 cycles for each digit
    //Refreshed every 16ms (~60Hz)

always@(negedge clock)
begin
    if (digit == 1)
        begin
            if (counter == 200_000)
                begin
                    digit = 2;
                end
            else
                begin
                counter = counter + 1;
                data = 4;
                end
        end
    else if (digit == 2)
        begin
            if (counter == 400_000)
                begin
                    digit = 3;
                end
            else
                begin
                    counter = counter + 1;
                    data = 3;
                end
        end
    else if (digit == 3)
        begin
            if (counter == 600_000)
                begin
                    digit = 4;
                end
            else
                begin
                    counter = counter + 1;
                    data = 2;
                end
        end
    else if (digit == 4)
        begin
            if (counter == 800_000)
                begin
                    digit = 1;
                    counter = 0;
                end 
            else
                begin
                    counter = counter + 1;
                    data = 1;
                end
        end 
end


always @ (*)
begin

    case (data)
        6'd0: cathodedata = 8'b00000011; //0
        6'd1: cathodedata = 8'b10011111; //1
        6'd2: cathodedata = 8'b00100101; //2
        6'd3: cathodedata = 8'b00001101; //3
        6'd4: cathodedata = 8'b10011001; //4
        6'd5: cathodedata = 8'b01001001; //5
        6'd6: cathodedata = 8'b01000001; //6
        6'd7: cathodedata = 8'b00011111; //7
        6'd8: cathodedata = 8'b00000001; //8
        6'd9: cathodedata = 8'b00001001; //9
        6'd10: cathodedata = 8'b00010001; //A
        6'd11: cathodedata = 8'b11000001; //B
        6'd12: cathodedata = 8'b01100011; //C
        6'd13: cathodedata = 8'b10000101; //D
        6'd14: cathodedata = 8'b00100001; //E
        6'd15: cathodedata = 8'b01110001; //F
        default: cathodedata = 8'b11111111; //default all off
    endcase

    if (setdp == 1) //decimal point
        cathodedata = cathodedata & 8'hFE;

    case(digit)
        0: anodedata = 4'b1111; //all OFF
        4: anodedata = 4'b1110; //AN0
        3: anodedata = 4'b1101; //AN1
        2: anodedata = 4'b1011; //AN2
        1: anodedata = 4'b0111; //AN3
        default:
        anodedata = 4'b1111; //all OFF
    endcase

end 
endmodule
```

Comment: Have you checked this in a waveform simulator?

Comment: Yes. My results are as expected. Each Anode enable signal is low when it's supposed to be and the correct cathode data is present during that time. When I download the file to my FPGA board (Basys2), I see "8" for about half a second at AN3 followed by a steady "4". AN2, AN1 and AN0 all remain off.

Comment: When debugging, it's far easier to bite off smaller chunks and test them separately to narrow down where a problem may lie.  It's a process of elimination.

Comment: You should probably change `=` to `<=` inside your `always @(negedge clk)` block. For reference look up blocking(=) vs non-blocking(<=).

Comment: Did you review any available logs created by the download/synthesis process, and make sure there are no warnings or errors?

Comment: `setdp` is never assigned and should be. You should add an asynchronous reset to the always block. During reset, assign digit, data, setdp, and counter to the preferred initial conditions.

Comment: @Greg I would also prefer to see async resets applied but I think it is common for FPGA designs to just initialise in the declaration eg `reg [19:0] counter = 0;` ?

Comment: @Greg It's unclear exactly what he's trying to do with the `setdp` signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too am using a basys2 and looking for a 7-seg driver. Nathan G's code did not work for me (using system verilog perhaps?), but I found this article: http://simplefpga.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/scrolling-or-moving-text-using-7.html?showComment=1362783256904#c5783969326158067433 and I cannibalized it to my own ends.The modified code is below. It should take (although I haven't checked the decoding fully yet) four hex values and display them on the 7-seg. In my example my board now says 'FAAF' (because getting this working was faf)

ucf file taken from digilent site:

```
# Pin assignment for DispCtl
# Connected to Basys2 onBoard 7seg display
NET "seg<0>" LOC = "L14"; # Bank = 1, Signal name = CA
NET "seg<1>" LOC = "H12"; # Bank = 1, Signal name = CB
NET "seg<2>" LOC = "N14"; # Bank = 1, Signal name = CC
NET "seg<3>" LOC = "N11"; # Bank = 2, Signal name = CD
NET "seg<4>" LOC = "P12"; # Bank = 2, Signal name = CE
NET "seg<5>" LOC = "L13"; # Bank = 1, Signal name = CF
NET "seg<6>" LOC = "M12"; # Bank = 1, Signal name = CG

NET "dp" LOC = "N13"; # Bank = 1, Signal name = DP

NET "an<3>" LOC = "K14"; # Bank = 1, Signal name = AN3
NET "an<2>" LOC = "M13"; # Bank = 1, Signal name = AN2
NET "an<1>" LOC = "J12"; # Bank = 1, Signal name = AN1
NET "an<0>" LOC = "F12"; # Bank = 1, Signal name = AN0
```

Top level module has this:

```
module top_level(     

//clock input
input CLK,

output [7:0] seg,
output dp,
output [3:0] an

);    

scrolling_name scrolling_name(
.clock(CLK),
.reset(RESET),
.a(seg[0]),
.b(seg[1]),
.c(seg[2]),
.d(seg[3]),
.e(seg[4]),
.f(seg[5]),
.g(seg[6]),
.dp(dp),
.an(an),
//.XPosition(XPosition),
//.YPosition(YPosition)
.XPosition(8'hFA),
.YPosition(8'hAF)
);

endmodule
```

and the file I took from the guy in the link and have edited is:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module scrolling_name(
input clock,
input reset,
output a,
output b,
output c,
output d,
output e,
output f,
output g,
output dp,
output [3:0] an,
input [7:0] XPosition,
input [7:0] YPosition
);

reg [28:0] ticker; //to hold a count of 50M
wire click;
reg [3:0] fourth, third, second, first; // registers to hold the LED values

always @ (posedge clock or posedge reset) //always block for the ticker
begin
if(reset)
ticker <= 0;
else if(ticker == 50000000) //reset after 1 second
ticker <= 0;
else
ticker <= ticker + 1;
end

reg [3:0] clickcount; //register to hold the count upto 9. That is why a 4 bit     register is used. 3 bit would not have been enough.

assign click = ((ticker == 50000000)?1'b1:1'b0); //click every second

always @ (posedge click or posedge reset)
begin
 if(reset)
  clickcount <= 0;
 else if(clickcount == 8)
   clickcount <= 0;
  else
  clickcount <= clickcount + 1;

end

always@(posedge clock)
begin
fourth = XPosition[7:4]; 
third = XPosition[3:0]; 

second = YPosition[7:4]; 
first = YPosition[3:0]; 
end

//see my other post on explanation of LED multiplexing.

localparam N = 18;

reg [N-1:0]count;

always @ (posedge clock or posedge reset)
 begin
  if (reset)
   count <= 0;
  else
   count <= count + 1;
 end

reg [6:0]sseg;
reg [3:0]an_temp;

always @ (*)
 begin
  case(count[N-1:N-2])

   2'b00 :
    begin
     sseg = first;
     an_temp = 4'b1110;
    end

   2'b01:
    begin
     sseg = second;
     an_temp = 4'b1101;
    end

   2'b10:
    begin
     sseg = third;
     an_temp = 4'b1011;
    end

   2'b11:
    begin
     sseg = fourth;
     an_temp = 4'b0111;
    end
  endcase
 end
assign an = an_temp;

reg [6:0] sseg_temp;

always @ (*)
 begin
  case(sseg)
   0 : sseg_temp = 7'b1000000; //to display 0
   1 : sseg_temp = 7'b1001111; //to display 1
   2 : sseg_temp = 7'b0100100; //to display 2
   3 : sseg_temp = 7'b0110000; //to display 3
   4 : sseg_temp = 7'b0011001; //to display 4
   5 : sseg_temp = 7'b0010010; //to display 5
   6 : sseg_temp = 7'b0000011; //to display 6
   7 : sseg_temp = 7'b1111000; //to display 7
   8 : sseg_temp = 7'b0000000; //to display 8
   9 : sseg_temp = 7'b0011000; //to display 9
   10 : sseg_temp = 7'b0001000; //to display A
   11 : sseg_temp = 7'b0000011; //to display B
   12 : sseg_temp = 7'b1000110; //to display C
   13 : sseg_temp = 7'b0100001; //to display D
   14 : sseg_temp = 7'b0000110; //to display E
   15 : sseg_temp = 7'b0001110; //to display F

default : sseg_temp = 7'b1111111; //blank
endcase
end

assign {g, f, e, d, c, b, a} = sseg_temp;
assign dp = 1'b1;

endmodule
```

Please excuse the horrible formatting/indenting - there is a combination of his, mine, and adding four spaces to get stack overflow to recognize it as code. I don't have time to make things pretty unfortunately. I can bundle all this together and put it on dropbox if you would like.

Nathan

Comment: I just ran my code, there was one little error that I fixed. (I got the port declarations wrong) If yours works, thats great.  But I would consider reorganizing the layout of your code to make it more readable.

Comment: @Nathan G - Yeah, the port declarations were one of the errors that popped up... But in the end the segments just stayed blank. Don't really know why, and I was in a bit of a rush, so I just moved on. Perhaps something really basic like the pin assignments. I guess if the original poster finds my code useful I will clean it up in a few days/when I have time.

Comment: Guys, thank you both for your code. I feel really stupid. My code was actually fine. My UCF was incorrect. I had clock mapped to RCCLK(C8) instead of MCLK (B8). Doh! I did learn more about verilog examining both of your codes. I also like the scrolling text example you found as I may implement that in the future.

Comment: @BlueSolrac - It's always the little errors that take the longest time to find in my opinion. A good tip is to download the ucf file from the digilent site: http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?Prod=BASYS2 - you can uncomment the lines you want from their file without having to go through the effort of looking up the pin assignments (and they should be correct too unlike the PCB markings).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a modified version of one of my pet projects.  It should do exactly as you wanted: display `4 3 2 1` on the 4dig7seg display. I tested it on an Amani GTX CPLD, and it should transfer cleanly to your board.

I like separating projects into separate modules to keep organized.  The top level module takes the on board clock as an input and outputs 14 signals to a four-digit-seven-segment serial display.  **Make sure the pins are correctly assigned.**

```
module SevenSeg(clk, odig, onum, col, ap); 

input clk;         // 50 MHz oscillator 
output [3:0] odig; // selected digit output
output [7:0] onum; // selected display output
output col = 1;    // turns the colon off 
output ap  = 1;    // turns the apostrophe off 

wire clock;        // divided oscillator to slow the display output 

parameter a   = 8'b11111110; // low means on, high means off  
parameter b   = 8'b11111101; // these are just parameters  
parameter c   = 8'b11111011; // defining each of the 
parameter d   = 8'b11110111; // seven segments 
parameter e   = 8'b11101111; // making life easier
parameter f   = 8'b11011111; 
parameter g   = 8'b10111111; 
parameter dp  = 8'b01111111; 

parameter off = 8'b11111111; 

parameter one    =  b & c;             // parameters for outputs
parameter two    =  a & b & d & e & g; 
parameter three  =  a & b & c & d & g; 
parameter four   =  b & c & f & g; 


    wire [7:0] port1 = one;   // This is set up so these can change dynamically...
    wire [7:0] port2 = two;   // ... if so desired.     
    wire [7:0] port3 = three;
    wire [7:0] port4 = four;


slowclk m1(clk, clock);   // divides clk by 500, for 50 MHz in, 100 kHz out 

digitize m2(clock, port1, port2, port3, port4, odig, onum); // rotates the digit outputs 

endmodule
```

---

Next I have a simple clock divider.  The *case count = 500* can be modified to divide your clock to whatever frequency you like.  The output should look fine in the range of about 120 Hz to about 2 MHz.

```
module slowclk(clk, clock); 

input clk; 
output reg clock; 
integer count; 

always @(posedge clk) 
case(count)      
500: begin clock <= clock + 1; count <= 0; end   // Change 500 to any divisor you like
default:  count <= count + 1;   
endcase 
endmodule
```

---

Then we have to rotate the digits.  Note if you change the anodes and cathodes at the "same" time, there will be a small leakage current into the neighboring segments causing a "ghost" effect.

```
module digitize(clock, num1, num2, num3, num4, odig, onum); 

input wire clock; 
input [7:0] num1; // rightmost digit 
input [7:0] num2; 
input [7:0] num3; 
input [7:0] num4; // leftmost digit 

output reg [3:0] odig; 
output reg [7:0] onum; 

parameter [7:0] off = 8'b11111111; 

reg [3:0] dstate; 

always @(posedge clock) 
case(dstate) 
0:begin   odig   <= 4'b0001; dstate <=  1; end 
1:begin   onum   <= num1;    dstate <=  2; end 
2:begin   onum   <= off;     dstate <=  3; end  // off states prevent 'ghosting' 
3:begin   odig   <= 4'b0010; dstate <=  4; end  // when changing output digit 
4:begin   onum   <= num2;    dstate <=  5; end 
5:begin   onum   <= off;     dstate <=  6; end 
6:begin   odig   <= 4'b0100; dstate <=  7; end 
7:begin   onum   <= num3;    dstate <=  8; end 
8:begin   onum   <= off;     dstate <=  9; end 
9:begin   odig   <= 4'b1000; dstate <= 10; end 
10:begin  onum   <= num4;    dstate <= 11; end 
11:begin  onum   <= off;     dstate <=  0; end 
default:  dstate <= 0; 
endcase 
endmodule
```

Answer (score -1):

Towards the end you have :

```
always @(*) begin
...
  if (setdp == 1) //decimal point
    cathodedata = cathodedata & 8'hFE;
```

`always @*` implies a combinatorial block, that is no flip-flop to break up loops etc. Your simulator may not have caught this but I would expect it to have real problems in synthesis.

Basically you have cathodedata driving itself.

I would replace this with something like:

```
always @(*) begin
...
  if (setdp == 1) //decimal point
    cathodedata_mask = cathodedata & 8'hFE;
  else 
    cathodedata_mask = cathodedata;
```

Comment: I think I disagree that his code there would cause a synthesis problem, I'm pretty sure I've used constructs like that before. `cathodedata` would already be set by the prior case statement, so I think that this is essentially like putting a mux on the output of the case statement, and driving the output of the case statement to one input, and driving the output of the case statement anded with `FE` to the other port. The output wire would be named `cathodedata`.

Comment: I see your point @Tim, cathodedata is always assigned just before this. I think I would avoid coding it like that though.