# Block is unconnected and will be trimmed Verilog

Tags: verilog, xilinx

In the following code `BCDtoSevenDecode` takes 4 bit input and decodes it for Seven Segment display. The decoded result is stored in `resultx` variable. All resultx variables are then passed to a 4x1 Mux. I am using xilinx to compile this verilog code. The code compiles with the warning:

`WARNING:Xst:647 - Input <clk> is never used. This port will be preserved and left unconnected if it belongs to a top-level block or it belongs to a sub-block and the hierarchy of this sub-block is preserved.`

`WARNING:Xst:647 - Input <reset> is never used. This port will be preserved and left unconnected if it belongs to a top-level block or it belongs to a sub-block and the hierarchy of this sub-block is preserved.`

`WARNING:Xst:1306 - Output <select> is never assigned.`

I am unable to figure out the problem so I am consulting experts here.

Here is the code:

```
 module Counter(input clk, input reset, output[3:0]SsdEnable, output [6:0]DecodedOut, output reg [3:0]temp1, output reg [3:0]temp2 , output reg [3:0]temp3, output reg [3:0]temp4);


wire [6:0] Result1,Result2,Result3,Result4;
reg [3:0] count1,count2,count3,count4;

wire [25:0]loop;
wire [11:0]counter;

reg [1:0]Sel;

SevenDecoder u1(count1,Result1);
SevenDecoder u2(count2,Result2);
 SevenDecoder u3(count3,Result3);
SevenDecoder u4(count4,Result4);

Mux u5(Result1,Result2,Result3,Result4,Sel,DecodedOut );
Decoder_2x4 u6(Sel,SsdEnable);


always @(posedge clk or negedge reset)
begin
 if(!reset)
  begin
count1<=0;
count2<=0;
count3<=0;
count4<=0;

//counter=0;
 end
 else
  begin
if(loop==49999999)
begin
    count1<=count1+1;
    if(count1==10)
    begin
        count1<=0;
        count2<=count2+1;
    end

    if(count2==10)
    begin
        count2<=0;
        count3<=count3+1;
    end

    if(count3==10)
    begin
        count3<=0;
        count4<=count4+1;
    end

    if(count4==10)
    begin
        count1<=0;
        count2<=0;
        count3<=0;
        count4<=0;
    end

    temp1<=count1;
    temp2<=count2;
    temp3<=count3;
    temp4<=count4;
end
  loop=loop+1;
 end

end



always @(posedge clk or negedge reset)
begin

if(!reset)
Sel=0;
else
    begin
    if(counter==1000)
    begin
    Sel=0;
    end

end
 counter=counter+1;
end


endmodule


module SevenDecoder(input [3:0]i , output[6:0] out);

assign out[0]= (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 6 || i == 7 || i == 8 || i == 9) ? 0 : 1;
assign out[1] = (i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 3 || i == 4 || i == 7 || i == 8 || i == 9) ? 0 : 1;
assign out[2] = (i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 4 || i == 5 || i == 6 || i == 7 || i == 8 || i == 9) ? 0 : 1;
assign out[3]= (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 6 || i == 8 || i == 9) ? 0 : 1;
assign out[4]= (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 6 || i == 8) ? 0 : 1;
assign out[5]= (i == 0 || i == 4 || i == 5 || i == 6 || i == 8 || i == 9) ? 0 : 1;
assign out[6]= (i == 2 || i == 3 || i == 4 || i == 5 || i == 6 || i == 8 || i == 9) ? 0 : 1;

endmodule

module Mux(input [6:0]in1,input [6:0]in2,input [6:0]in3,input [6:0]in4, input [1:0]sel, output [6:0]out);

assign out=(sel==0)?in1:
            (sel==1)?in2:
            (sel==2)?in3:
            (sel==3)?in4:0;
endmodule



module Decoder_2x4(input [1:0]sel, output [3:0]selSSD);

 assign selSSD=(sel==0)? 4'b1110 :
                (sel==1)? 4'b1101 :
                (sel==2)? 4'b1011 :
                (sel==3)? 4'b0111 :0;

endmodule
```

What is causing this problem?

EDIT:

I have posted the whole code here. I have been trying to debug it but I have failed to find the bug in this code.

This code doesn't give anyoutput. It should display changing values on `cnt1,cnt2,cnt3,cnt4` as a proof that values are incrementing but it is not.

Comment: There's a very clean version that works great and is easy to understand here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15264689/1906816

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating answer based on current revison of code in question, some of the further info may no longer apply to the latest version of the question.

The Question contains this block of code:

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge reset)
begin

if(!reset)
Sel=0;
else
    begin
    if(counter==1000)
    begin
    Sel=0;
    end

end
 counter=counter+1;
end
```

I would update it to the following :
`counter` is not reset so will be x, x+1 is till x.

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge reset) begin
  if(!reset) begin
    Sel     <= 0;
    counter <= 0;
  end
  else begin
    counter <= counter+1;
    if(counter==1000) begin
      Sel <= 0;
    end
  end
end
endmodule
```

I noticed this in part of the code, you will not be getting the behaviour you want:

```
  if(iterator==20) begin
    if(out[3:0]==9) begin
      out[3:0] <= 0;
      out[7:4] <= out[7:4]+1;
    end
    ...
    out[3:0]<=out[3:0]+1;
```

The non-blocking assignments mean it does not block the execution of the simulator until the end of the timestep when it copies the value across. So I do not see how `out[3:0]<=0` is ever executed as it is unconditionally overridden by `out[3:0]<=out[3:0]+1;`

The top level module is CounterTOP, with output [7:0] output, this is being driven by the [6:0] output 'out' of MUX. Therefore the MSB (most significant bit) of out will be z, that is undriven.

**Some recommended improvements below:**

I would avoid mixing the case of variables, you Sel and modules called Mux. I prefer to keep everything lowercase except (local) parameters which are uppercase. Under score delimited is often used over CamelCase. ie I would have written module SevenDecoder as seven_decoder. I think this aids readability and some simulators are not case sensitive so when using mixed case it is possible to have variables differentiated by case which start interfering with each other. Mixing case of variables makes typos more likely.

Bugs are easier to see with correctly aligned code, editing can also be faster as you can start using the column mode of you editor.

Reviewing code is much easier if you use named ports, without it is very hard to spot connectivity errors.

```
Mux az(
  .sel(        ), 
  .in1( result1),
  .in2( result2),
  .in3( result3),
  .in4( result4),
  .clk( clk    ),
  .rst( reset  ),
  .out( out    )
);
```

Although unrleated to the current error you are seeing I suggest you fix your assignments in `always @(posedge clk)` blocks.

You are currently using blocking `=` assignments which can lead to differences between simulation and hardware. which becomes very difficult to debug. in clock triggered block you should use non-blocking `<=` assignments.

The nested if statements could also be replaced with a case statement:

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge reset) begin
  if(~reset) begin
    iterator <=0;
    i        <=0;
  end 
  else begin
    case(iterator)
    10, 20, 30 : begin
      i <= i+1;   
      iterator <= iterator + 1;
    end
    40 : begin
      i        <= i+1;
      iterator <= 0;
    end
    default : iterator <= iterator+1;
  endcase
end
```

Comment: Ok. but please when you get home, tell me the bugs in my code so that I can avoid them in future

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't connected any `select` lines to your mux.

Comment: If I do that inside Mux, I get illegal assignment error, so I am doing this inside CounterTOP. I have updated the code

Comment: But `select` is still not in the port list `Mux az(result1,result2,result3,result4,clk,reset,out);` !

Comment: I am posting the updated code, Now it gives trims out `select` and says it is never used

Comment: your `iterator` & `select` stuff should be in the module that instantiates the mux, ie `CounterTop`, otherwise you'll not be able to connect them! They're down in `BCDtoSevenDecode` in your latest code. You'll also need to declare `iterator` and `select` as `reg` too. And - as you have it `select` will become a latch because you haven't specified a value for it in all the branches of the `if` statement!

Comment: I am posting the whole code. I have tried to debug it but I am messing it up.